# how to deploy asp.net mvc 5 with source code attached (for debugging purposes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I want to deploy an asp.net mvc5 website but with source code not with binary files.

Is it possible?

I've tried several tutorial on the net for attach my VS2013 to IIS7 but the problem is I don't have the source code so I can't put any break point.

Comment: Your 3 choices are set up remote debugging (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx); install VS on the web server, copy your entire project, and use RDP to login and run VS there, or set up IIS Express on your dev box to match the prod server as closely as possible and debug locally. The latter is probably easiest.

Comment: @tvanfosson - He can also configure a local instance of IIS, rather than IIS Express

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do here.  You do know you can debug on your local computer, right?  Or is there a problem that only appears on your host server?  Where is your host server?  Is it a shared web hosting?  There are way too many factors here.  But in general, no.. deploying your site with source code won't change anything.  You need the source where you're debugging, not on the server.

Comment: I want to debug and trace my web app on the production server. and remote debugging doesn't show me the code! that's my real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer :
http://www.ronaldrosier.net/blog/2013/08/15/debug_a_aspnet_website_on_local_iis_with_custom_hostname_in_visual_studio_2013

I can run my web app from local IIS and that's what I was looking for.